# UIActionSheet and UIAlertView focus on iPad

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, uikit, uialertview, uiactionsheet

I have some troubles with UIActionSheet and UIAlertView on iPad
in fact, i use an alertView as a pop up with textfields and buttons to enter a 
date, when i click on the button the UIActionSheet who contains my UIDatePicker is supposed to show, it shows but i don't have focus to pick a date
the focus is still on the alertview and the ActionSheet is in the background 
(but on iphone there is no problem it works fine)

is there some code to add for the iPad?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

In the clickedButtonAtIndex method of your AlertView explicitly dismiss the alertView and show your ActionSheet.

using;
- (void)dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex animated:(BOOL)animated and present the action sheet

e.g

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
[alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO];
if(buttonindex==1{
[self showActionSheet]
}
}
```

> NB for Iphone you may not need to dismiss the alertView.